# How to make @MyRequestMapping in spring

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I impl @Get annotation like following code

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET])
@ResponseBody
annotation class Get(vararg val value: String = [])

@RestController
class Ctrl {
    @Get("/test-get")
    fun testGet(): String {
        return "test get"
    }

    @Get("/test-get2")
    fun testGet2(): String {
        return "test get"
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
class Server

internal class SpringTestHelperTest {
    @Test
    fun testTestServer() {
        runApplication<Server>()
        var h = Http()
        println(h.get("/test-get").body)
        println(h.get("/test-get2").body)
    }
}
```

but raise error:

```
Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'ctrl' method 
ktlibspring.Ctrl#testGet()
to {GET [/]}: There is already 'ctrl' bean method
ktlibspring.Ctrl#testGet2() mapped.
```

I just confused, why spring builtin @GetMapping can be impl but my @Get will raise error, how to make my @Get?

I guess I need a way to redirect @Get target fn to @RequestMapping target

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

I refer @GetMapping impl

"Ambiguous mapping" it's because all my @Get inner @RequestMapping use value=[], I should use @AliasFor redirect @Get value to @RequestMapping value

following is my @Get impl

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET])
annotation class Get(
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.name].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val name: String = "",
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.value].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    vararg val value: String = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.path].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val path: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.params].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val params: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.headers].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val headers: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.consumes].
     * @since 4.3.5
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val consumes: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.produces].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val produces: Array<String> = []
)
```